# Its lock file has been locked by another process - Neo4j Embedded

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-embedded

I am developing a embedded application of the Neo4j and I try run this but I get this error:

> Store and its lock file has been locked by another process:
>   /home/dev/neo4j-community-2.3.2/data/graph.db/store_lock. Please
>   ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory
>   is writable (required even for read-only access)

I know that is because the neo4j server application is running and it lock the directory to writable for another application.

But I want run both, the neo4j server with browser studio and my embedded application.

I am use the community edition 2.3.2 in Linux.

How can I do it?

It is possible in enterprise version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the very same directory you can only run at most one instance at a given time.

Enterprise edition enables master-slave replication, so the `graph.db` is folder is propagated from master to slave instance. This would be an option for you.

I assume you want to access you embedded instance via the browser. See this blog post http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/11/21/neo4j-browser-with-embedded.html - be aware this one is based on 2.1 - as far as I remember in 2.3 some things have changed since then.

Comment: Stefan Armbruster: This WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper is deprecated and reading the documentation more closely, they not recommend use embedded, especially when we update the app we would have to stop the Neo4j service. It is not good. I read also that the best way to develop an application in server side is create a extension plugin. Do you have any suggestion about this? Thanks.

Comment: writing "unmanaged extensions" is a good way to deploy your own code in a Neo4j server.